# How we can Use Custom theme in share Point Server 2010?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, themes

I wanted to change the look and feel of my share point server 2010 site. I have use office Power font to create my custom theme. .Thmx file. 
I am just wanted to know how to use the custom style to use in share Point server 2010. Like  earlier we did in share point serve 2007 to create a theme folder. I want a fix solution. Like if i wanted to deploy my theme into server 2010. I will not get trouble.

Thanks & regards,
Basant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following two links show you where you need to upload the .thmx theme file to be able to use it.

http://www.toddbaginski.com/blog/archive/2009/11/02/how-to-create-a-custom-theme-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx.aspx

http://spdavid.com/post/2010/01/16/Custom-SharePoint-2010-Themes.aspx